# Subscript indices error while indexing array within symbolic function symsum

Tags: arrays, matlab, symbolic-math

I'm trying to solve an easy recursive equation, but I'm encountered with very rudimentary problems that I think a MATLAB expert can easy resolve. 
So here is the short version of my code:

```
clear all
%%%INPUT DATA
gconst = [75 75];
kconst = [200 200];
tau = [.01667 .14153];
%%% TIME Span
t = [0 .001 .002 .003 .004 .005];
%%% Definition of the functions g(x) and k(y)
syms g(x) k(y)
g(x) = gconst(1)*exp(-x/tau(1))+gconst(2)*exp(-x/tau(2));
k(y) = kconst(1)*exp(-y/tau(1))+kconst(2)*exp(-y/tau(2));
%%% Defining initial conditons
nu = zeros(1,7);
nu(1)= 3.64e-1;
nu(2)= 3.64e-1;
%%% nu(3) is required
int(sym('i'))
nu(3)=nu(1)*(3*k(t(3)-t(2))+g(t(3)-t(2))-g(t(3)))...
     +symsum(nu(i)*(3*k(t(3)-t(i+1))-3*k(t(3)-t(i-1))... %symsum line 1
     +g(t(3)-t(i+1))-g(t(3)-t(i-1))), i, 1, 3))... %symsum line 2
     /(3*k(0)+g(0));
```

You can ignore the whole `symsum` part, because without, the code still doesn't work. 
It is a very straightforward code, but after running it, I get this error:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

This error is found in the line where I defined `nu(3)`. 
I'd like to hear your comments.

EDIT 1: k(y) instead of k(x).

EDIT 2: zeros(1,7) instead of zeros(7).

NOTE 1: The code works without the `symsum` part and after EDIT 1.

Comment: I do not have the symbolic math toolbox, what is the value of `int(sym('i'))`?

Comment: You don't declare `i` . So for example nu(i) will give you the classical `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

Comment: Just don't use `i` as a variable, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: At least one issue is that `nu` is a numeric array, but you're trying to assign a symbolic expression to it, which won't work. Define `nu` as symbolic: `nu = zeros(7,'sym')`, or in older versions of Matlab: `nu = sym(zeros(7))`.

Comment: You also declare `k(y)` as a symbolic function but never define it (instead you define `k(x)`).

Comment: @horchler the same would apply for `t` - but in Matlab 2015 it doesn't seem to make any difference anymore?

Comment: I already have declared `i`and I even changed it to `ii` as the link suggests, but that's not the issue. @horchler a symbolic `nu` returns a massive equation, how can I change it to a single number, and honestly `nu` as an array does the job as well (without the `symsum` part though). And `k(y)` was mistakenly written as `k(x)` and I edited that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you want can't be done.**

The reason is, that you are indexing an array `t = [0 .001 .002 .003 .004 .005]` with the symbolic summation index `i`.

So while

```
syms i
S1 = symsum( i, i, 1,3)
```

works

```
syms t i
t = [1 2 3];
S1 = symsum( t(i), i, 1,3)
```

won't work, and there is no way around it, because the values `1 ... 3` are **evaluated after indexing**. You need to rethink your approach completely.

---

Apart from that you probably want `k(y)` instead of `k(x)`. That was the reason why the code didn't work without the symsum part neither.

Using `i` as a variable name is not an issue anymore, but shouldn't be used to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: It is possible to get around the order of evaluation "issue" in your second answer by using the old string notation (slower and not recommended by The MathWorks) and `eval`: `S1 = eval(symsum('sym(t(i))', i, 1,3))` (the added `sym` is so the sum is evaluated symbolically). I would rewrite the code rather than use this though. One could also call to the MuPAD engine as well, but it doesn't seem worth it here.

Comment: @horchler It does not work, I tried a hundred other things as well. I could imagine to create the whole expression within `symsum` as string, e.g. with a loop and evaluate that.

Comment: @thewaywewalk `k(x)` was a typo. Now the only problem is the `symsum` part. And as you suggested for a _string and loop_ instead of `symsum`, that is not feasible, because it's a recursive equation, i.e. in order to solve the equation for `nu(3)` you need `nu(1)` and `nu(2)`, and I want this for say `nu(70)`. And as far as I know, one can not use a loop inside an equation.

Comment: I was able to write the `symsum` part with two rather easy `for` commands combined with an `if`.